# Facing error for Poppler gem on GitHib CI workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am facing this `GObjectIntrospection::RepositoryError::TypelibNotFound: Typelib file for namespace 'Poppler' (any version) not found` error when the GitHub's CI workflow runs and it always fails due to it. I tried adding `glib2` and `gobject-introspection` gems as well, but nothing works for me. I already have `poppler` gem in my gemfile. I am using `aws-sdk-s3` gem for uploading the files to AWS using active storage and the `poppler` gem is being used to preview the files in the application. Locally everything is working fine for me.

I am using `rails 6.1` and `ruby 2.7.5`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this install step in your `workflows/ruby.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Install Poppler
  run: |
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt -y install libpoppler-glib-dev
```